# Parameters which affect the transmission strength of a signal (vibrations) in a solid?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

I'm working on a pair of devices - a signal injector and a matched detector for vibrations in solids. My background is not in acoustics, so I'm looking for pointers on what are the parameters that affect the propagation of the vibrations of the solid. Let's say the injected signal on one end of the solid is a known force or power value and I know the acoustic impedances of both the solid and the actuator, as well as the length of the solid and what environment it's in. How would I be able to model or 'guesstimate' if the signal would reach the other end of the solid?

I have a copy of ["Understanding Acoustics" by Steven L. Garrrett](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-030-44787-8.pdf),but looking through it, nothing immediately jumps at me as what I'd need to read more in-depth; I'm hoping to avoid studying this book wholly to gain insight for this problem. Are there some papers I'd be recommended to take a look at?

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Shape and structure of the apparatus will matter at least as much as the material properties of its constituent parts. A 1m steel wire, a 1m steel sphere, and a 1mx1m square of steel ball bearings will have different acoustic properties, for example.

Comment: Are you talking about structural mechanics? Could we assume that the structure has a linear behaviour, or at least a linear model for small perturbation of the system works? Which kind of forcing (harmonic, impulsive, train of steps, chirp signal, ...) are you using? I'd be glad to start answering your question, but it's better to know some more information in advance, to avoid going out-of-topic

Comment: @gs that's fair, I just don't know **how** the shape and structure would matter mathematically. In my case, we can assume a rod or a solid rectangle.

Comment: @basics not quite. I think we can assume that it's possible for my problem to have a linear behavior/solution, at least to entertain the idea. Let's see...an example of the experiment for me would be akin to mounting a solid bar or rod (say, 1m of length) and then tapping it with a wrench with a force of 1N. Would the vibration make it to the end of the bar? What if the bar is 10m long and in water/covered by sand? Would the vibration make it to the end in this case? Wrt forcing, I can only assume what each means and I'd like to know more about them. The example above is impulsive, correct?

Comment: @NickS. how is your bar constrained (clamped/hinged? at one point/many points? You could add a sketch of your set-up to your question). Which material is your bar built from? How are you loading your structural element? Axial force, Shear/Bending, Torsion? I.e. in which direction are you hitting your bar? If the bar is in "free air" we could easily answer your question, once you have given us these further details. When the bar is immersed in water or sand, the problem could be more tricky, and I need to think

Comment: @basics for the example, you can assume the two ends are put on two tables and the middle is floating. Choose any convenient metal. Iron? Steel? For the single hit, just swinging down on one of the ends. I'm not looking for the specific solution to the example though, I just want to know what goes into determining whether the vibration will reach the other end or no and if I can do an approximation by hand/NumPy rather than teach myself a full-fledged FEA suite.

Comment: "reach the other end" is not a meaningful condition. You need to define a minimum amplitude that may still be detected by your sensor. So, it is not just a matter of the medium.

Comment: @nasu that's fair, I'm not completely sure how to translate sensor requirements into an amplitude, however. For an accelerometer or a geophone it's either acceleration or velocity, and for something like a contact microphone, it's in V/mm of the membrane movement, which, so far, empirically I'm getting mV, so 1/1000th of a millimeter? The spring constant is 20N/m, not sure if that could help me define the amplitude of the signal that's "injected" into the solid.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime Istart a new problem and am trying to figure out what should be accounted for, I like to start looking for length scales.  Without knowing what your exact problem is, I can only provide a high-level guide.  Here is a quick list of length scales I usually think about:

- **Wavelength**: This includes needing to know the wave speed and the frequency content of the signal.  Since you are looking at solids, don't forget that there is a different wavelength for shear and compression modes.  The sound speeds depend, in turn, on the mass density and elastic moduli.  Thus, you should be aware of the material properties of the system.
- **Domain size**: If you have an unbounded domain (free propagation), this length scale is infinite; same with lengths much larger than the wavelength.  If you have a long, narrow tube, you would then look at the cross-sectional perimeter.  If the domain scale is not infinite, you are going to be looking at reflections, and probably different vibration modes.  Look up things associated with wave propagation, resonance, and maybe waveguides.
- **Displacement amplitude**: If you are assuming infinitesimal signals, you are dealing with linear acoustics.  If you are expecting displacement rates (ok, this is a velocity rather than a length) that are comparable to the sound speed, you are going to need to look up nonlinear phenomena.
- Are you including other physics, like viscosity?  There are length scales there that will lead to additional phenomena you should account for.

You can use relative length scales to tell you what features are most important for your experiment.  For example, I know you are interested in vibrations in solids, so absolutely the material properties and frequency content will be critical to incorporate.  Ask yourself what you are trying to measure, and hopefully that will guide you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you look at one of my comments above, I provide an example. 1. With regards to wavelength, to extend that example, if I put a speaker on a solid oscillating at a frequency f, can I assume the solid will also experience the vibration at that frequency? If I just tap it once, will the input frequency be the tap or the solid vibrating from the tap? 3. Infinitesimal signals with respect to what? Is there a quantifier of that? 4. I'm not including any other physics, at least yet. Trying to learn as much as I can about mechanics & acoustics right now.